# IF tiny box hide refresh page

Tags: javascript

I am using [TinyBox2](http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinybox2/) on my page and I want to refresh the page when the TinyBox is closed.

I use this to close tiny box:

```
window.parent.TINY.box.hide();
```

Any idea how to refresh the page after I call this function?

Sorry for my english

John

Comment: `window.location.reload()` will refresh the page. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: your english is better than most native english speakers, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

An easy (and bad) way to do it would be (untested) :

```
window.parent.TINY.box.hideAndReload = function() {
  this.hide();
  window.location.reload();
}
```

Then you can just call `window.parent.TINY.box.hideAndReload()`. But that's some kind of a hack, so I'm not sure if you should use this without being absolutely sure this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps a little to,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function closeJS(){location.reload();}
</script>
```

I use self the closeJS for this to refresh after the main page.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is still looking, a working solution is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      parent.window.location.reload();
      parent.TINY.box.hide();
 </script>
```